Perfect infinitve with future tenses

I will plan to do it when she comes

I will plan to have done it when she comes

I will have planned to do it when she comes

I will have planned to have done it when she comes

I will be planning to do it when she comes

I will be planning to be doing it when she comes


MEANING

I start my planning after her arrival

I don't know

My plan is ready before her arrival

I don't know

I will be in the middle of planning when she comes

The same as 5


Can you check and provide the meaning of the rest?

There's some unfortunate ambiguity since we have so many events here: the present in which we're speaking, the time "when she comes," whatever time the planning happens, and whatever time the "doing it" happens. For instance, "I will plan to do it" is an unlikely statement because essentially it expresses a "plan to plan." Not all verb tense can be used in all situations in ways that make sense. It might be easier to recast all these in their present-tense equivalents, like "I plan to," "I have planned to," etc. Even then, not all would be idiomatically likely, and some have the same meaning.

Actually, thinking about these longer, they all have the same ambiguity: whether or not they make perfect sense or are idiomatic, all of them make clear that something happens "before she comes," but is it the planning or the doing, or both? None of these constructions can make that clear. And as I said, they're all unlikely, because we don't often put "plan" in the future tense, except in transitive uses like "the generals will plan their attack when they gather tomorrow."

It's impossible to answer this accurately. For one thing, plan can mean 'decide to do something' as well as 'make a plan of action'. So (1) can mean I will arrange to do it when she comes as well as I will start my planning when she comes. For another thing, some of your sentences don't mean anything sensible. (Andy posted his comments while I was writing this.)
